# python condensing functions for +-*

Tags: python, math, vector, operations

I've got 3 math operation functions I need to use on a point3 value. I was wondering if someone could shed any light on a way to better write these functions in a more clean and condensed fashion please.

Thank you.

```
ptA = [10.0, 20.0, 30]
ptB = [50, 50 ,50]
percent = .50


def addPoint3(ptA,ptB):

    idA = ptA[0] + ptB[0]
    idB = ptA[1] + ptB[1]
    idC = ptA[2] + ptB[2]

    return [idA,idB,idC]

def subtractPoint3(ptA,ptB):

    idA = ptA[0] - ptB[0]
    idB = ptA[1] - ptB[1]
    idC = ptA[2] - ptB[2]

    return [idA,idB,idC]

def percentagePoint3(ptA,percentage):

    idA = ptA[0] * percentage
    idB = ptA[1] * percentage
    idC = ptA[2] * percentage

    return [idA,idB,idC]



add = addPoint3(ptA,ptB)
sub = subtractPoint3(ptA,ptB)
per = percentagePoint3(ptA,percent)
print add,sub,per
```

Comment: I think this question may be more suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), another Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a `Point` class and implement the arithmetic operators. A naïve example would be:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.coords = args

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(*[(x + y) for (x, y) in zip(self.coords, other.coords)])

    def __repr__(self):
        coord = ', '.join("{}".format(x) for x in self.coords)
        return "<Point ({})>".format(coord)
```

Which you could use like this:

```
ptA = Point(10.0, 20.0, 30)
ptB = Point(50, 50, 50)
>>> print ptA + ptB
<Point (60.0, 70.0, 80)>
```

You could expand it to use `__sub__` and `__mul__`, and make it a bit more robust, because right now the implementation assumes many things:

- That you always add points (this would break if you add an integer, for example)
- That both points are the same dimension

All those things could be tested, to then generalize the methods.

Comment: +1 for Class implementation. Gotta love portability and cleanliness!

Comment: Actually, `zip` will truncate to whichever has fewer dimensions.

Comment: It will, but maybe those are not the semantics he's looking for :-)

Comment: Plus, it will still break on the case you don't pass an interable

Comment: This is great stuff Ricardo, thank you very much for the help and explanation I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to simplify these. For example:

```
def addPoint3(ptA, ptB):
    return [a+b for a, b in zip(ptA, ptB)]
```

or

```
def percentagePoint3(ptA, percentage):
    return [pt * percentage for pt in ptA]
```

You might also consider implementing a class, rather than the lists, so you can define these as instance methods (for an example of this, see Ricardo Cárdenes' answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[ptA + ptB for ptA,ptB in zip(ptA, ptB)]
```

And change operators for substractions etc.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue then the fastest vectorized operations in python come not from lists but from `numpy`.  Example:

```
import numpy as np

ptA = np.array([10.0,20.0,30])
ptB = np.ones(3)*50

pt3 = ptA + ptB #done with c/blas libraries under the hood.
```